# Excel - find function of a Nonlinear Regression

Tags: excel, regression, non-linear-regression

I'm trying to solve a task in Excel that seems simple but i'm missing something. I have 2 data columns:

- Column A - year Column
- Column B - percentage value showing how much more
  people were spending compared to the previous year

I am translating this from Italian but the task says to:do the regression of the data for the purpose of estimating the value in Column B for the middle of a year in Column A

I created a scatter graph and my understanding is that I need to take a value on the X-axis (the mid point between 2000 and 2001 for example) and find the corresponding value in the y-axis.

Googling i found some similar case related to **nonlinear regressions**. But basically from what I understand I need to somehow find the formula (y=mx+c) which defines the graph and then substitute X and find Y

[image]

[UPDATE]

I was able to find the trend line option in Excel which also adds the equation of the function but the trend line is straight so the equation doesn't help much

[image]

The only trend line that helps is the Moving Average but that one doesn't have a formula because I guess its just the average of 3 data points.

I used the Moving Average method to get some data points but they don't follow the graph very well, they just make straight lines

Comment: This curve appears to match a high-order polynomial trendline

Comment: the option is located at the right side of your second picture..

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks sigmoidal, so you could use a sigmoid function to model it, see image below for details.

[image]

To find the values of the parameters in the equation (a, b and c), I used Solver to minimise E27 by varying C1:C3.

If you want to see more details of fitting an equation using Solver, then my video might help: https://youtu.be/bDt4EqqGSlg it shows the fitting of a different type of equation but demonstrates the same principle.